# Django admin access not granted

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to run /admin for the project that i am creating.i am facing two problems here

1.when i point my browser to 127.0.0.1/admin/ it says page not found but when i point the browser to 127.0.0.1 then i get the list of files in my project file how to rectify this

2.Every time i restart apache there are no pyc file created??

```
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  546 2012-07-11 15:45 manage.py
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 2012-07-12 17:53 __init__.py
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 2012-07-12 18:03 test
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  114 2012-07-12 18:03 __init__.pyc
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-07-12 18:20 tmp
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4489 2012-07-12 18:20 settings.py
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  585 2012-07-12 18:34 urls.py
```

I have included `django.contrib.admin` in installed apps in settings.py file and also this is the urls.py file below

```
  from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

  # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
  from django.contrib import admin
  admin.autodiscover()

  urlpatterns = patterns('',
      # Examples:
      # url(r'^$', '{{ project_name }}.views.home', name='home'),
      # url(r'^{{ project_name }}/', include('{{ project_name }}.foo.urls')),

      # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
      # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

      # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
      url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
  )
```

`EDIT`

I have not created any module as yet..Should  i be creating a module then access admin ??

`EDIT1`

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

# This application object is used by the development server
# as well as any WSGI server configured to use this file.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/mysite/wsgi.py
  WSGIPythonPath /opt/mysite

  <Directory /opt/mysite>
  <Files wsgi.py>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  </Files>
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that your apache is improperly configured.

Check out these docs:

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi)

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

To be sure, you could start Django on its on development server and see if you can access the admin area.

---

Try this in your django.wsgi:

```
import os,sys

#add your django project in PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/django/project/path/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='projectName.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

apache_django_wsgi.conf:

```
Alias /uploads/ "pathTo/uploads/"
<Directory "pathTo/uploads/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

Alias /static/ "pathTo/sitestatic/"
<Directory  "pathTo/sitestatic/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "pathTo/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "pathTo/apache/django.wsgi">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then, in your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf (or wherever it is located)

```
Include "/pathTo/apache_django_wsgi.conf"
```

Comment: i have created the wsgi.py file and have placed it in mysite as descirbed in the docs.Please look at question for edit1..

Comment: what do you mean by "I have not created any module as yet" ?

Comment: sorry i have included one of my module in installed apps.Please see edit 1 for more details

Comment: One question : where exactly should  1.django.wsgi 2.apache_django_wsgi.conf reside......My  created project resides in /opt/tex/site

Comment: I have them in ./myProject/apache .. so you can create a directory /opt/tex/site/apache and place them there

Comment: i have put django.wsgi in /opt/tex/site and pointed httpd.conf to this

Answer (score 1):

click `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, you need the port. If you just go too `http://127.0.0.1` you will see only the list of files. You don't use `runserver`?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood than. I hope you will resolve your issue.